# She goes/went to bed before midnight at the weekend

Tags: tense, verbs

> She ____ to bed before midnight at the weekend. "goes" or "went"

This question was on my English test. What is the correct answer?

Comment: This question should migrate to English Learners Stack Exchange. Please tell us the work you have done on the question yourself. We like to help those who try to help themselves.

Comment: **It depends on what you mean**.

Answer (score 0):

*Went.*
If it were "She ____ to bed before midnight *on weekends*", then goes would have been appropriate.

Comment: "on weekends" is more American - see [this on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75466/at-on-the-weekends)